# Comparison of variable in php

Tags: php, if-statement

I have 3 variables named `$a`, `$b`, and `$c`. These variables hold dynamic value which comes from database.

I want compare these variable if `$a`, `$b`, `$c` hold space means " " then print `no message` and if variable `$a`, `$b` hold space and `$c` hold message print message,if `$a`, `$c` hold space and `$b` hold message print message, if `$b`, `$c` hold space and `$a` hold message print message. Please help me. Thanks

My code is

```
if(($_GET['ms1']== " " ) && ($_GET['ms2'] == " ") && ($_GET['ms3']==  " "))

    {
      print"<p style=color:red;text-align:center;font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,Serif;>";
      echo "No Message From Court.";
      print"</p>";
      print"<p style=color:green;text-align:center;font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,Serif;>";
      echo "Thank You";
      print"</p>";

    }

 elseif(($_GET['ms1']==' ') && ($_GET['ms2']==' '))


      {
            print"<p style=color:red;font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,Serif;text-align:center;>";
             echo '3'.$_GET['ms3'];
            print"</p>";


      }

 elseif(($_GET['ms1']== ' ') && ($_GET['ms3']==' '))


      {
            print"<p style=color:red;font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,Serif;text-align:center;>";
            echo '2'.$_GET['ms2'];
            print"</p>";


      }

    elseif(($_GET['ms2']==' ') && ($_GET['ms3']==' '))


      {
            print"<p style=color:red;font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,Serif;text-align:center;>";
            echo '1'.$_GET['ms1'];
            print"</p>";


      }
```

Comment: What is the problem? By the way your a bound to run into problems using single quotes as a setting, you should at the very least use `===` if you want to check for exactly one single quote.

Comment: problem is that variable contain space so i did not compare at all please help me sir

Comment: i want if all variable contain space then print no message but in these three if any one contain string message then print message.

Comment: so, trim the spaces! `if((trim($_GET['ms1'])=="" ) && (trim($_GET['ms2'])=="") && (trim($_GET['ms3'])==""))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
    .p_red { color:red;text-align:center;font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,Serif; }
    .p_green { color:green;text-align:center;font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,Serif; }
</style>

<?php
function isEmpty($string) {
    return ($string === ' ');
}

$a = $_GET['ms1'];
$b = $_GET['ms2'];
$c = $_GET['ms3'];

if (isEmpty($a) && isEmpty($b) && isEmpty($c)) {
    echo "<p class='p_red'>No Message From Court</p>";
    print"<p class='p_green'>Thank You</p>";
}

if (!isEmpty($a) && isEmpty($b) && isEmpty($c)) {
    echo "<p class='p_red'>1. $a</p>";
}

if (isEmpty($a) && !isEmpty($b) && isEmpty($c)) {
    echo "<p class='p_red'>2. $b</p>";
}

if (isEmpty($a) && isEmpty($b) && !isEmpty($c)) {
    echo "<p class='p_red'>3. $c</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple implementation:

```
 <?php
   foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {
     if (strpos($key, 'ms') {
       if (!strpos($val, ' ')) {
         echo '<p style="color:red;font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,Serif;text-align:center;">';
         echo str_replace('ms', '', $key).$_GET[$key];
         echo '</p>';
       }
     }
   }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would advise copying the $_GET entries to local variables ($a, $b, $c) *after* checking that those entries are set (*isset* call). If any/all aren't, consider defaulting the local variables to ' ' (a single space). Then you can safely check `if ($a == ' ')...` etc., knowing that there are values you can work with.

You should consider pulling out the common HTML code into one place, rather than repeating it 3 times.

```
$a = (isset($_GET['ms1'])? $_GET['ms1']: ' ';
$b = (isset($_GET['ms2'])? $_GET['ms2']: ' ';
$c = (isset($_GET['ms3'])? $_GET['ms3']: ' ';
echo '<p style="color:red;font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,Serif;text-align:center;">';
if ($a == ' ' && $b == ' ' && $c == ' ') {
   echo "No Message From Court.";
   print"</p>";
   print"<p style=color:green;text-align:center;font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,Serif;>";
   echo "Thank You";
} elseif ($a == ' ' && $b == ' ') {
   echo '3'.$c;
} elseif ($a == ' ' && $c == ' ') {
   echo '2'.$b;
} elseif ($b == ' ' && $c == ' ') {
   echo '1'.$a;
}
echo '</p>';
```

Note that you should be wary of a user injecting nasty HTML (iframes, etc.) when simply echoing out user input (it's very easy to make up your own GET fields).